# Widewine Drm in Exoplayer Error

Tags: android, drm, widevine, exoplayer2.x

I am implementing an OTT application on Exoplayer Android. We are protecting our contents with Widewine DRM.But we got the error shown below.

```
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err: com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.UnsupportedDrmException: android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm object.
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.FrameworkMediaDrm.newInstance(FrameworkMediaDrm.java:50)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.cinesoft.cinehome.player.PlayerActivity.buildDrmSessionManager(PlayerActivity.java:483)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.cinesoft.cinehome.player.PlayerActivity.initPlayer(PlayerActivity.java:398)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.cinesoft.cinehome.player.PlayerActivity.onPlayRequestResult(PlayerActivity.java:1308)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.cinesoft.cinehome.api.services.ConnectToServer$3.onResponse(ConnectToServer.java:503)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.cinesoft.cinehome.api.services.ConnectToServer$3.onResponse(ConnectToServer.java:483)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err: Caused by: android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm object.
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaDrm.native_setup(Native Method)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaDrm.<init>(MediaDrm.java:215)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.FrameworkMediaDrm.<init>(FrameworkMediaDrm.java:57)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.FrameworkMediaDrm.newInstance(FrameworkMediaDrm.java:48)
 06-13 17:31:53.641 18652-18652/com.cinesoft.cinehome.android W/System.err:     ... 14 more
```

And the code is shown below

```
mediaDataSourceFactory = buildDataSourceFactory(true);
        mainHandler = new Handler();
        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

        videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        eventLogger = new EventLogger(trackSelector);
        if (JsonParser.sStr_drmStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            AndroidDeviceIdentifier androidDeviceIdentifier = new AndroidDeviceIdentifier();
            UUID drmSchemeUuid = null;
            drmSchemeUuid = UUID.fromString(androidDeviceIdentifier.getUniqueDeviceIdentifier(PlayerActivity.this));
            drmSessionManager = null;
            if (drmSchemeUuid != null) {
                String drmLicenseUrl = ConnectPortalSettings.WIDEVINE_LICENSE_SERVER_URL;
                String[] keyRequestPropertiesArray = new String[]{};
                //                drmLicenseUrl = intent.getStringExtra(DRM_LICENSE_URL);
                //                keyRequestPropertiesArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra(DRM_KEY_REQUEST_PROPERTIES);
                try {
                    drmSessionManager = buildDrmSessionManager(drmSchemeUuid, drmLicenseUrl,
                            keyRequestPropertiesArray);
                } catch (UnsupportedDrmException e) {
                    int errorStringId = Util.SDK_INT < 18 ? R.string.error_drm_not_supported
                            : (e.reason == UnsupportedDrmException.REASON_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME
                            ? R.string.error_drm_unsupported_scheme : R.string.error_drm_unknown);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Drm Error Code", String.valueOf(errorStringId));
                    return;
                }
            }
            @SimpleExoPlayer.ExtensionRendererMode int extensionRendererMode =
                    ((BaseApplication) getApplication()).useExtensionRenderers()
                            ? (false ? SimpleExoPlayer.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER
                            : SimpleExoPlayer.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_ON)
                            : SimpleExoPlayer.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF;
            LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
 // 3. Create the player

                 player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl,
                    drmSessionManager, extensionRendererMode);
        } else {
            LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
        }
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was one of my pitfalls.  The uuid of "edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed" is needed not some device property.  Also as a sanity check it may be worth while to go back to the example app and point it to one of google's servers to verify the device, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of data in the dump which can be confusing and distracting, but the error you need to focus on is:

> android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm
>   object

Are you running this on an emulator?
You probably need to run it on a real device instead in order to test.
See more about this at: 
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1616

If you are not running on an emulator and you are running on a device, it can be a problem with the device you are running it on as indicated by:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2260

Also, notice that when we focus on that error we also recognize it is a :
**UnsupportedSchemeException**

> Exception thrown when an attempt is made to construct a MediaDrm
>   object using a crypto scheme UUID that is not supported by the device

from:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/UnsupportedSchemeException.html

Comment: : I am running code in a real device and the second link you are provided is a dead end. I am retrieving UUID using the below code

Comment: public static String getDeviceUUID(Context ctx) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] hash = makeHash(getMac(ctx), getSerialNumber(ctx));
        return createUUIDFromHash(hash);
    }

Comment: There are no dead ends. There are just places where you have to jump the fence sometimes.  :)  The point was that that link also mentions, "It is related to your device".  I'll try the method on a couple of my devices and let you know.

Comment: Thank you for your kind concern

Comment: We have to look closer at UnsupportedEncodingException -- https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/UnsupportedEncodingException.html
When that exception occurs it should fill the string with the reason it occurred.  It may not like the encoding used on the hash variable that you're passing in.

Answer (score 1):

As raddevus says, that error is saying that the player does not recognise the DRM scheme identifier.

Different DRM's have different scheme ids - widevines is "urn:uuid:EDEF8BA9-79D6-4ACE-A3C8-27DCD51D21ED".

It is possible that the wrong scheme id has been included or that the encoding is not being read correctly.

It is also worth checking that the MPD contains the protection information - the spec says it should be in the MPD and in the MP4 PSSH header also but some packagers include it in only the MP4 PSSH header, in which case Exoplayer will not find it in the MPD.